i'm creating a board game using canvas ,i suceed to do it ,but i can't interact with each case ,for example to assign a new color,how could i do that
hello everyone and thanks fo your concern,
every thing is in the question title.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var randomColor =function(){return  Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);}
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width  = window.innerWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var tuiles = {}





var hexa = function(x,y,s){


tuiles[x+' '+y] = canvas.getContext("2d")

  tuiles[x+' '+y] .beginPath();
    tuiles[x+' '+y] .moveTo(x,y);


tuiles[x+' '+y] .lineTo(x+(s/2),y-(s/5))

tuiles[x+' '+y] .lineTo(x+s,y)

tuiles[x+' '+y] .lineTo(x+s,y+(s/2))
 
tuiles[x+' '+y] .lineTo(x+(s/2),y+(s/2)+(s/5))

tuiles[x+' '+y] .lineTo(x,y+(s/2))
 
tuiles[x+' '+y] .lineTo(x,y)
 

     tuiles[x+' '+y] .stroke();
     tuiles[x+' '+y]  .closePath();
 
tuiles[x+' '+y] .fillStyle ="#"+randomColor()
tuiles[x+' '+y] .fill();
 
}
 

var col =function(x,y,s,c,l){
if(c > 0)
{
hexa(x,y,s)

col(x+s,y,s,c-1)

}

}


var row =function(x,y,s,c,l){

col(x,y,s,c,l)


if(l > 1){

    if(l % 2 == 0){
hexa(x,y,s)

row(x+(s/2),y+(s/2)+(s/5),s,c,l-1)
}
else{

hexa(x,y,s)

row(x-(s/2),y+(s/5)+(s/2),s,c,l-1)


}
}
else{

console.dir(tuiles)

}


}


var grid = function(x,y,s,c,l){

row(x,y,s,c,l)

}



grid(100,100,ctx.canvas.height/15,15,15)

i'd like to store each hexa case in tuiles object this way i could manage to change the color of each indepently.
but the only way ifound to do that is to create a new canvas element for each hexagone i draw ,and it is ridiculous.
thanks for your help
i put my code below

So basically you have drawn the board and now you'd like direction on making it interactive? What have you tried so far on making it interactive? If you havent tried anything (in terms of code) then you could start by finding some simpler tutorials online. "Pong" might be a good start in terms of simplicity.

i tried a few thing,for example ,i add a mouse event listener on ctx ,it work but it apply only to the last created case.

i tried few other thing but it allways lead to the same result. i tried also  new Path2D() ,it's a nice options but it is limited and you can't change the color of the draw. i made a bunch search but what it come's out it's that it's not possible without making a new canvas element for each new case but it seams to be a non sens to me

from MDN :  "Later calls to this method on the same canvas element, with the same contextType argument, will always return the same drawing context instance as was returned the first time the method was invoked. It is not possible to get a different drawing context object on a given canvas element."

okay but how to deal with that?

it was a very good idea to fins a pong canvas exemple,i found how it work,i'll post th answer later cause it's late

There are couple of approaches. But either way, you should have some sort of function to convert from mouse position to the data and the other way around.
In case of your hexagons, you can use a function to check if a point is inside a polygon. So to summarize:

Representation of shapes in memory
A function to convert mouse position to a memorized shape
A function to convert a shape to canvas positions (draw)



var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var randomColor = function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const { width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
ctx.canvas.width = width
ctx.canvas.height = height

var hexagons = []

function drawPolygon(polygon, color) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(polygon[0].x, polygon[0].y);
  for (var i = 1; i < polygon.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(polygon[i].x, polygon[i].y)
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#" + color
  ctx.fill();
}

var hexa = function(x, y, s) {

  var polygon = [
    { x: x, y: y },
    { x: x + (s / 2), y: y - (s / 5) },
    { x: x + s, y: y },
    { x: x + s, y: y + (s / 2) },
    { x: x + (s / 2), y: y + (s / 2) + (s / 5) },
    { x: x, y: y + (s / 2) },
    { x: x, y: y },
  ]

  hexagons.push(polygon)
  drawPolygon(polygon, randomColor())
}


var col = function(x, y, s, c, l) {
  if (c > 0) {
    hexa(x, y, s)
    col(x + s, y, s, c - 1)
  }
}


var row = function(x, y, s, c, l) {
  col(x, y, s, c, l)
  if (l > 1) {
    if (l % 2 == 0) {
      hexa(x, y, s)
      row(x + (s / 2), y + (s / 2) + (s / 5), s, c, l - 1)
    } else {
      hexa(x, y, s)
      row(x - (s / 2), y + (s / 5) + (s / 2), s, c, l - 1)
    }
  } else {
    // console.dir(tuiles)
  }
}


var grid = function(x, y, s, c, l) {
  row(x, y, s, c, l)
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev) {
  var cx = ev.offsetX
  var cy = ev.offsetY

  // find which hexagon contains mouse position
  var hexa = hexagons.find((hexa) => isPointInPoly(hexa, { x: cx, y: cy }))
  if (hexa) {
    drawPolygon(hexa, randomColor())
    canvas.style.cursor = "pointer"
  } else {
    canvas.style.cursor = ""
  }
})

grid(20, 20, ctx.canvas.height / 4, 4, 4)


function isPointInPoly(poly, pt) {
  // from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5295
  for (var c = false, i = -1, l = poly.length, j = l - 1; ++i < l; j = i)
    ((poly[i].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[j].y) || (poly[j].y <= pt.y && pt.y < poly[i].y)) &&
    (pt.x < (poly[j].x - poly[i].x) * (pt.y - poly[i].y) / (poly[j].y - poly[i].y) + poly[i].x) &&
    (c = !c);
  return c;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="200"></canvas>




Ver nice approach, but i should said than i allready had it before.with this method, i can't use js and said for example, hexagon[0][5].color = green, and this is what i'm looking at. Using an object(not an array) to store and access the hexagon when i want to change it. Let say i would like to load a map, with the object i could do that very easily. I found a way to do it i'll post it later today. But thanks a lot to you mr goldman

the point of my answer is identifying hexagon from mouse interaction
